# Backbone Router needs to ignore "index.html"

Tags: backbone.js

I'm not in a position to modify the htaccess of the server and want to use Backbone Router.
The problem is I'm stuck with a static html file in the url (index.html)

How do I get Backbone to ignore the index.html?

Thanks in advance.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "page-one" : "pageOne"
    },
    pageOne : function(){},
    pageTwo : function(){},
    pageThree : function(){}
});

scn.router = new Router();

Backbone.history.start({root: "/Backbone/index.html"});
```

I had on pushState, which I don't need.  That was THE problem.  For now.

Comment: Can you show us the routes in your Backbone.Router object?

Answer (score 3):

pushState was the problem.  I turned it off then my issues were solved.